# Postprocess Sequelize finders with Express

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am new to Javascript.
I am developping an API to retrieve information from MySQL with :

- Node.js
- Express
- Sequelize

I developed the following controller based on a Sequelize finder (findByPk, to retrieve information by a primary key). There are several nested includes.

```
exports.findByPk = (req, res) => {
  Poi.findByPk(req.params.id,{
        attributes: [
            'name',
            'description'
        ],
        include: [{
            model: Source,
            attributes: ['originalId'],
            where: {source: 'google'}
        },{
            ...
        }]
    })
    .then(data => {
        res.send(data);
    })
};
```

As far as I understand, the finder outputs a relatively complex Sequelize instance object `data` which is passed in res.send (but the API gives access to a proper Json).

I need to postprocess `data` before passing the result in res.send :

- I need to retreive information from a Google API using the `data` fields, and add this information to the API output
- I need to compute some values based on the `data` fields, and add these values to the API output (long story short, it cannot be part of the Sequelize query because of a known issue in Sequelize)

How to retrieve the values I need from `data` ? Should I treat it as a regular javascript object, understand its structure, and manually retrieve the values I need ? Or are there methods for that ?

After that, how to add information to `data` ? Should I actually add information to `data`, or create a new object ? Should it be a Sequelize object or can it be a regular json-like javascript object ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just turn `data` (that is actually an instance of the `Poi` Sequelize model) into a plain JS object and afterwards work with it in a regular way:

```
.then(data => {
  const plainObject = data.get({ plain: true });
  plainObject.newProp = 1
  // some work here including accessing Google API
  ...
  res.json(plainObject);
```